# Is SQL injection possible even on a prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql-injection, penetration-testing

I read many articles on Stack Overflow regarding how SQL injection can be prevented by using prepared statements

But is there any way to do SQL injection even on prepared statements or is it 100% safe?

Below is my java code

```
 String query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=? and password=?";

 ps=con.prepareStatement(query);  

 ps.setString(1,username);
 ps.setString(2,password);

 rs = ps.executeQuery();

 status = rs.next();

 if(status==true){
.....
}else{
....
}
```

I tried some sql injection queries like

Some Inputs:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'xxx@xxx.xxx' OR 1 = 1 LIMIT 1 -- ' ] AND password = md5('1234');

SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'xxx@xxx.xxx' AND password = md5('xxx') OR 1 = 1 -- ]');
```

I have also tried with some more queries but as the (single quote)' is escaped(/') none of the SQL injection queries seem to work.

Kindly suggest me if there are any SQL injection queries/techniques which can be applied to do SQL injection in the above code.

Comment: PreparedStatements should guard against SQL injections, doing quoting themselves and escaping. However there are many database engines, and many java JDBC drivers, so some exception might not be perfect. In my experience SQL injections and PreparedStatements still happen when some xxxx tries to use a dynamic string to construct something like `categ IN(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)`. And you still need to guard against storing user-entered JavaScript later displayed as HTML content.

Comment: `statements` as `parameters` inside of `prepared statements` will not be executed - thats guaranteed by design so your "experience" actually never happened **or** your database had/has serious bug. `Prepared statements` will have all of the execution done before any parameter is applied - meaning the internal lookup logic itself cannot be modified by the parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query : `String query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=? and password=?";` is safe, because whatever the parameters can be, it will still be executed as a simple select. At most, it will end browsing a whole table.

But prepared statement is just a tool and (bad) programmers may still misuse it.

Let's look at the following query

```
String query = "SELECT id, " + paramName + " FROM Users WHERE username=? and password=?";
```

where `paramName` would be a parameter name. It is only as safe as `paramName` is, because you use directly a variable to build the string that will be parsed by the database engine. Here `PreparedStatement` cannot help because JDBC does not allow to parameterize a column name.

So the rule here will be :

- avoid such a construct if you can !
- if you really need it, double check (regexes, list of allowed strings, etc.) that `paramName` cannot be anything other than what you expect because **that control is the only prevention** against SQL injection

Comment: Thanks...for the answer it was very helpful....is there any other way or trick to perform sql injection with my above code...